# Separate MTU for IPv4 and IPv6 on Linux

Tags: linux, ipv6, mtu

Is it possible to define MTU on an interface with different values for IPv4 and IPv6 on a Linux machine?
It seems that command ifconfig  MTU  defines the same MTU for both IPv4 and IPv6.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What distribution are you on?

Answer (score 2):

This might help you. 
Setting a higher value in

```
 /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/mtu 


command sudo sh -c "echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/mtu
```

But turns out it can be reset regularly by the router. Quote from a comment in this link. [How to configure a large mtu (linux)](https://superuser.com/questions/476967/how-to-configure-a-large-mtu-linux)

> This value gets updated/reset regularly through Router Advertisement.
>   RA can be disabled by writing 0 to accept_ra in the same folder under
>   /proc.

Comment: Of course if you don't accept RA you might not even get an IPv6 address or route.